# Convenient Windows equivalent to tail -f logfile?

Tags: windows, log-files, tail

Is there some convenient alternative to this on Windows? I always miss this away from Linux. And no I don't consider Cygwin or some other bash port to be "convenient". :)

Either a small app that'll do it from the command line or will have it open in a window. I need to be able to essentially pause it too, which won't affect the log file, but will allow me to scroll up through the buffer.

Answer (score 18):

[BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) has a great balance of features and light weight. The highlighting has saved me countless hours.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 14):

Options:

1. [unxtools](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) includes a port of `tail`, including `-f`.
2. PowerShell's `get-content` includes an extra option `-wait` when using the file system which performs the same function (see `help filesystem` for this and other cmdlet extensions from the filesystem provider).

Answer (score 8):

Using PowerShell:

> Get-Content C:\LogFile.txt -Wait

Comment: What refresh interval? For a reason I ignore, it lags behind BareTail.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) port of [`tail`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).  GnuWin32 is similar to Cygwin in that it's a Windows port of Unix tools but it is completely different in intent.

Instead of trying to turn your Windows system in to a Unix Workstation, each GnuWin32 binary is compiled so it can run as an independent tool.  There are separate downloads so you can just [download the tools you want](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html).  (This makes GnuWin32 preferable to the MinGW ports as well, as the MinGW utilities require all the MinGW libraries to be in place.)

Comment: I was looking for something like that, since I try to run away from cygwin...

Answer (score 2):

[LogExpert](http://logexpert.codeplex.com/) is the one FMPOV: tabs, local file tail, but also accross network using SFTP (SSH) or CIFS (UNC-based), versatile highlighters and more

Answer (score 1):

mTail - http://ophilipp.free.fr/op_tail.htm

It's an alternative to tail -f combined with grep.

Comment: I'd recommend any of the alternatives over mTail, it's a buggy and unintuitive application that is completely unfinished.

Comment: I'll second that!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the excellent [TraceTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tracetool). Amongst many other features, it supports tail with pause/resume.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another great Tail utility is Tail for Win32: http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/
It is pretty fast and can be used to show you real-time tail on a file which is very convenient when troubleshooting web logs or security logs in production.
I also used it to determine what user activity is like at any given time on web servers.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [PowerShell Community extension](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=powershell%20community%20extension&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://pscx.codeplex.com/&ei=NV8NT7rIIIzKtAbsgZXDBA&usg=AFQjCNF9dJWsa1GZmoUlLg9GlbxVBtt-Hw&sig2=RwTOol2Cf2Zg-ddp0nm6jg).
Get-FileTail -f *FileName* 
I think this is the best combination of Unix tail flair on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[SnakeTail](http://snakenest.com/snaketail/) is a Windows tail program that can monitor and search log files.

[Log Expert](http://www.log-expert.de/) is another good alternative.

Here is a good list of other  [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/tag/tail/)