# Windows Small Business Server 2011 64 Bit - where to find tail

Tags: windows-server-2008, 64-bit, tail

I am looking for a tail alternative which can be installed on a Windows Small Business Server 2011 64 Bit (from this old [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/7263/convenient-windows-equivalent-to-tail-f-logfile))? I tried mTail, LogViewer and both failed. Do you have any suggestion for me?
I tried

Comment: what log(s) are you trying to view - a Windows event log?  Also, what failed?  Install, no results, what?

Comment: Own logs created by a log4net text appender.

Comment: Install failed...No real 64-bit version or illegal package...

Comment: Cygwin tools might help?

Answer (score 3):

I use GnuWin32 tail and it works fine on 64-bit WIndows

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/