# Monitor syslog (RFC 5426) on Windows Server 2008

Tags: logging, syslog

I have setup in a Windows Server 2008 a syslog server using NXLog http://nxlog-ce.sourceforge.net/. I've configured some routers in the network to send syslog messages (RFC 5426) to the server (UDP 514) and it's working great, saving all the messages in `C:\Syslog\devices.log`.

In Linux servers I can monitor the syslog log file using the command `tail -f /var/foo/bar/syslog` so I could see incoming events. What would the equivalent in Windows Server that support displaying the incoming messages? I just don't want to reload the file in any file editor, wait to open the whole log (when I just care about the tail), and scroll to the bottom, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question really has nothing at all to do with syslog.

This has already been covered here: [Convenient Windows equivalent to tail -f logfile?](https://serverfault.com/questions/7263/convenient-windows-equivalent-to-tail-f-logfile)

Comment: and much like most of the answers in the linked question, the answer is to download the windows port of tail.exe and use tail -f just like you normally would.

Comment: Thank you, but yes, it does, I wanted a tool that could support syslog format highlight, but somehow that is against stackoverflow policies.

Comment: That sounds like a feature (again) of the tail executable(s) that you are looking for, and not actually a feature of the syslog server in any way.